# Yandex почта отправка mail php?

Tags: php, email, яндекс-почта

Есть страница "спасибо", пользователь заходит на нее с email-письма полученного по рассылке.

Нажав на кнопку-ссылку (пример ссылки - `http://site.ru/thanks/manager=victor&email=test@test.ua&telephone=13131313)` 
он тем самым отправляет заявку менеджеру о том что был переход по ссылке и менеджер перезванивает ему и т.п.

```
$user_email = isset($_GET['email']) ? $_GET['email'] : '' ;
$user_telephone = isset($_GET['telephone']) ? $_GET['telephone'] : '' ;
$manager = isset($_GET['manager']) ? $_GET['manager'] : '' ;


switch($manager) {
    case 'victor' :
        $sendto = 'mail@mail';
        break;
    case 'dobrinina' :
        $sendto = 'mail2@mail';
        break;
    default:
        $sendto='mail3@mail';
}


$recepient = $sendto;
$sitename = "#Repost";

$msg  = "<html><body style='font-family:Arial,sans-serif;'>";
$msg  .= "<p><strong>Email:</strong> $user_email</p>";
$msg  .= "<p><strong>Телефон:</strong> $user_telephone</p>";

$pagetitle = "Заявка с рассылки! \"$sitename\"";

if(isset($_GET['manager'])) {
    mail($recepient, $pagetitle, $msg, "Content-type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\n From: $sendto");
```

На все популярные почты письма приходят, но на yandex почту, зарегистрированную как почта для домена, письма не приходят.

Приходит только вот такое письмо

```
Fwd: Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender  Распечатать
26 апр. в 16:22
Имя Имя <xxx@ya.ru>

Кому
xxx <xxx@xxx.ru>


 
-------- Пересылаемое сообщение--------
26.04.2016, 16:21, "Mail Delivery System" <mailer-daemon@server109.hosting.reg.ru>:
 
This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

  xxx@xxx.ru
    Unknown user

------ This is a copy of the message, including all the headers. ------

Return-path: <xxx@ya.ru>
Received: from u0050601 by server109.hosting.reg.ru with local (Exim 4.72)
        (envelope-from <xxx@ya.ru>)
        id 1av2vE-0003fT-TH
        for xxx@xxx.ru; Tue, 26 Apr 2016 16:21:00 +0300
Date: Tue, 26 Apr 2016 16:21:00 +0300
Message-Id: <E1av2vE-0003fT-TH@server109.hosting.reg.ru>
To: xxx@xxx.ru
Subject: Заявка с рассылки! "#Repost"
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 705:index.php
Content-type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
 From: xxx@xxx.ru
From: xxx@ya.ru

<html><body style='font-family:Arial,sans-serif;'><p><strong>Email:</strong> xxx@xxx.ru</p><p><strong>Телефон:</strong> xxxx</p>

 
-------- Завершение пересылаемого сообщения --------
 
 
-- 
С уважением,
```

В чем может быть проблема ??

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Там же вполне ясно написано:

```
The following address(es) failed:

xxx@xxx.ru
Unknown user
```

То есть почтовый сервер не смог доставить письмо, потому что такого почтового адреса на нём нет.

Проверяйте, что у Вас в переменных `$sendto`. В Вашем примере кода их содержимое `mail@mail` - верно ли оно заполнено в настоящем коде?